# File Upload Nil Photo Params Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I have a rails 4 app where I'm using jQuery File Upload to send requests to Carrierwave. My code looks like:

```
<input name='photo[image]' type='file' data-url='photos/create' multiple="true" class='fileupload'/>
```

and my jquery:

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
      $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        alert(file.name);
      });
    }
});
```

and my create action in the photos controller:

```
def create
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @photo.save
    format.json { render json: @photo }
  else
    format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

private
   def photo_params
     params.require(:photo).permit!
   end
```

and my Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

when I create a photo, carrierwave is correctly creating an image (in the public/uploads directory), yet for some reason my jQuery comes up with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I'm not sure what's causing this?

Comment: Does your web process have enough rights to write files?

Comment: Yes, I've been able to do photo uploading before with the same web app.

Comment: Do your webserver logs and/or Rails logs show the file transfer starting, progressing, breaking, or completing?

Comment: just post the server logs where this action fails.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your done callback try to log the returned data to console and show us the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should've left this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation, so my apologies.

I think you just need to use data.files rather than data.result.files

like this

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
      $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        alert(file.name);
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the json you respond with does not have the structure that the `done` callback expects. Since it's calling `each` on `data.result.files` I think the response will need to be structured more like this:

`render json: {result: { files: [@photo] } }`.

You can also try debugging the data returned by logging it to the javascript console in the callback

`done: function(e, data) { console.log(data) }`

Answer (score 1):

The structure of `data` object shows `results` field param as an object holding various field not related to files ; so the `data.result.files` results into the error with `.each()`

Use the following:

```
$.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
   alert(file.name);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RckMr/)** (Removed the server side code to catch the Object, just modify the above code.)

Answer (score 0):

First - try to explore your params.
File may by saved to tmp as temporary file and need to additional operations for move/rename